# Is there a simple way to mock many static methods in python/Django?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I'm coming from a Ruby/Rspec world where it is very simple to mock and setup tests/expects() statements to test static methods.

I was wondering if there is a simple way to test same things in Python.  Please disregard what the code is actually doing (i have changed many names in it) I have the following code:

```
def create_models(pr_dict):
    facility = FacilityCreator.doit(pr_dict)

    p = PCreator.doit(facility, pr_dict)

    pr = PRCreator.doit(p, p.recent, pr_dict)

    models_affected = {'f': f,
                       'pr': pr,}

    return models_affected
```

I have looked at unittest and unittest.mock but it doesn't seem to be eloquent solution if I have many static methods in my method. In other words, I would be doing a @patch within a @patch, etc. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the python [unittest module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html). It has mocking and patching modules

Comment: Thanks. Have done that but and looked at mock as well. it's not answering my 'static methods' question clearly.

Comment: You can create a "Mock Class" which has the methods you want to mock and the patch the entire class to avoid nested patch declarations